# Why won't this display the dynamic cgi?

Tags: git, perl, apache2, cgi

I am having a hell of a time getting my web server to display the CGI content. It's displaying the script... I've check dozens of times and all the files are in the right places and everything has the right permissions and EVERYTHING. UGH. What am I doing wrong? I've spent three hours and scoured every forum under the sun. I am setting up a hosted git repo for an internal department, and I am just dying. I even ran a tail -f against the logs and  I can't figure it out. I've been following this tutorial: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server. For reference, I have been reading this over and over: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/cgi.html#configuringapachetopermitcgi. I was good on everything until I got to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName gitserver
    DocumentRoot /var/www/gitweb
    <Directory /var/www/gitweb>
        Options ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AddHandler cgi-script cgi
        DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my Perl:

```
localdev1@brm-jedi:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ which perl
/usr/bin/perl
```

It's gotta be in here. I am misconfiguring something SOMEWHERE, but it's 1:30am and I've been at this since 4:30pm and I just cannot figure it out. Here is what I have:

```
#<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin something@somewhere
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
#</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName git.brmstorage.com
    DocumentRoot /brmstorage.git
    <Directory /brmstorage.git/>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName brm-jedi.brmstorage.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/gitweb/
    ScriptAlias /brmstorage.git/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory /var/www/gitweb>
        Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AddHandler cgi-script cgi
        DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As a side note, this is the only thing this web server is for, the repo and the gitweb functionality.

Please help me understand in as much detail as possible where I've gone wrong.

Is it that I have two virtual hosts that are both pointing to port 80? Should I that into one virtual host config?

Comment: Does `/var/www/gitweb/gitweb.cgi` exists *and* is executable?

Comment: Missing a plus sign in this line: `Options ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`

Comment: @VonC yes, it is there and executable.

@miller which part?
`Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` has it in my version...

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the problem is that cgid isn't enabled on apache.

Running

`a2enmod cgid`

`service apache2 force-reload`

Did the trick for me.